# Memory card Mount and Unmount programmatically in android

Tags: android

Is there any possible to mount, unmount the memory card programmatically in android . I searched lot of websites, but still not get accurate solutions for my problems .Please any one help me. Give some ideas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to safely remove SD card programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632039/how-to-safely-remove-sd-card-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: hope this link help to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/39792785/9501057
in this everything give in detailed

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be done. If it were, people could write malicious code to mount and unmount SD card from the phone.It was a good security decision to not allow apps to mount and unmount SD card. We can able to only READ and WRITE data.